# Using Gutters in Bootstrap 4 Layout

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use Bootstrap 4 to create a layout that has a gutter on each side. This layout has a nav row and a subnav row. I'm trying to create something that looks like this:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|      Welcome                                              Monday      |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|      Home                                             11.27.2017      |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|      Content will go here and wrap multiple lines and fill up the     |
|      screen.                                                          |
|                                                                       |
|                                                                       |
|                                                                       |
|                                                                       |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I want to use the `nav` element for styling. In addition, I want to collapse the second row on mobile, which is another reason to use the `nav` element. Still, I can't seem to figure out how to use a gutter when in desktop mode. When I use a `row`, it doesn't use the full available width. Currently, I'm using the following code:

```
<div style="background-color:#eee;">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand text-light" href="#">Welcome</a>

    <ul class="list-inline navbar-nav d-inline">
      <li class="list-inline-item nav-item">Today is Monday</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-light" style="background-color:#fff !important;">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-1"></div>
      <div class="col-8">Home</div>
      <div class="col-2 float-right">11.27.2017</div>
      <div class="col-1"></div>      
    </div>              
  </nav>

  <div class="row mx-0">
    <div class="col-10 offset-1" style="height:400px;">
      Content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How do I create a layout that includes gutters, while still using nav elements in Bootstrap 4?

Answer (score 0):

no not tow navbars...do one navbar two UL's one gets the hidden on mobile d-flexbox class and make one of the ul's the one hiiden on mobile the toggler collapse target..

In summary:

One navbar and two UL's

the one hidden on mobile has also the collapse class is the target of your toggler and than you should not have to use any d-flexbox hide classes as you will mark the full navbar as expand md

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, I guess I'm still confused. If I use one navbars, I don't see how I can get the background colors I want. I want the top most nav to have a black background and the second nav to have a whitebackground. Do you have an example in code?

Answer (score 0):

Gutters are not on the outside but rather the inside. The concept comes from publishing books (paper, go figure). Consider adding pl-5 and pr-5 to each of the nav classes and content div class. This will add padding to each side effectively giving extra space where you want it.

Here is the link to Bootstraps spacing. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/

I hope this helps.